# Google Maps Control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I tried to use [this Google Maps Control](http://www.shabdar.org/asp-net/70-google-maps-control-for-aspnet-part-1.html), but I keep getting this error:

```
The base class includes the field 'GoogleMapForASPNet1', but its type
(Vehicle_Tracking_System.GoogleMapForASPNet) is not compatible with the type of control
(ASP.googlemapforaspnet_ascx).
```

Comment: Exactly what are you toing to produce the error?  Can you describe how someone else can reproduce it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ??

Answer (score 0):

Note that the control is codefile.
You may check that :

- its containing page is also codefile (or change the control's source to codebehind)
- if you plan to use it in the .aspx.cs, you use the directive <@reference control="..."
- if your .aspx.cs is a partial class, the control should be declared automatically

Hope this will help,

Answer (score 0):

Note : Make sure that the version of the System.Web.Extension library is the same as what you have selected when you added the reference.

**Example you are adding "System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0"
and the reference has "System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0".**

Answer (score -1):

This is a better user control,
http://shabdar.org/asp-net/70-google-maps-control-for-aspnet-part-1.html

Comment: He states in the question that he is using that control.